# How to prove that optimal solution for ridge regression can be expressed in a following form?

Tags: least-squares, ridge-regression

We know that for ridge regression:
$$\beta = (X^TX + \lambda I)^{-1}X^Ty.$$
How can I prove that the optimal solution for beta can be expressed as $$\beta = X^T*V.$$ for some V

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck?